# identical strings in PHP show as not equal

Tags: php, string, comparison

I'm trying to compare two values from two different databases, but some of the values are returned as not equal, not matter what I try.

For one values, I'm doing this:

```
$a=(string)trim(strtolower($row['title']));
```

For the other values, I'm doing this:

```
$b=(string)trim(strtolower($res1['Utitle']));
```

When I compare them, I do this:

```
if ($a!==$b) {
   // code
}
```

I'm comparing about 2000 records and for only *some* of them, they show as not equal. For example, I can echo out the records that show as not equal, but see this:

```
a: IS BUS AUTO ANALYST
b: IS BUS AUTO ANALYST
```

I'm seeing both as identical. What am I missing?

Comment: Try `var_dump` to double-check the values. There may be some hidden characters.

Comment: It would be fun if you tried to do a levenshtein on it. `echo levenshtein($a, $b);` the output is integer and shows how many characters that is "wrong".

Comment: I'm guessing that the column `Utitle` contains Unicode characters, while `title` is just ASCII. There may be characters that look similar on the screen, but have different code points.

Comment: levenshtein($a,$b) returns 1.
var_dump returns NULL.

Comment: Ack. Sorry. var_dump returns 19 and 20, respectively. So there IS a hidden character. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using trim(). Testing a regex, this seems to work: $a=preg_replace('/[0-9][A-z] .','',$a);

Answer (score 2):

There were some hidden characters in one string so I'm using a regex to strip out everything I don't need.

```
preg_replace('/[0-9][A-z] .','',$a);
```